# Get specific reactions of specific message fetch return undefined

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I would try to get a specific reactions with reactions.cache.get() from messages.fetch("id") but it returned undefined. This is my code:

```
var messageGAL = await bot.guilds.cache.find(x => x.id == info.guildid).channels.cache.find(x => x.id == info.ChannelId).messages.fetch(info.MessageId)                                
                                console.log(messageGAL.reactions.cache.get("\uD83C\uDF89"))
```

Comment: There is any error? Because the only way I see `messageGAL.reactions.cache.get("\uD83C\uDF89")` being `undefined` is when there isn't this reaction in the fetched message.

Comment: Yes this message have this reaction

Comment: I'm lost, when I try your code it works for me.. you can try using `messageGAL.reactions.resolve("\uD83C\uDF89")` but I doubt this will work more than what you are trying right now.. if guild/channel/message fetched are undefined you should get an error so this not seems to be the issue.. I assume you already tried to test with other messages? Or we are missing something that is somewhere in your code.